# How to detect wear swipe to back event

Tags: android, wear-os

In Android when we press back button then we get event on `onBackPressed()` Method similarly when we swipe on wear from left to right then which methods get called ?

i want to know the callback method which get called on swipe so that i can send message to phone from wear.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: Any update on this?